# Given two identical beta distributions $Beta(\alpha ,\beta)$ and their covariance $\rho$, how to create a joint pdf which satisfies the condition

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, correlation

How to create a joint pdf which satisfies the condition that the marginal distributions are both $Beta(\alpha ,\beta)$ and covariance is $\rho$

Comment: Suggest see the paper by Olkin and Trikalinos (2014), _Constructions for a bivariate beta distribution_ ... https://www.brown.edu/academics/public-health/research/evidence-based-medicine/sites/brown.edu.academics.public-health.research.evidence-based-medicine/files/uploads/constructions_08Sep2014.pdf

Comment: Start from two independent Beta(a,b) random variables U and V and some independent Bernoulli random variable B with P(B=1)=p=1-P(B=0), and consider X=U, Y=BU+(1-B)V. Then X and Y are both Beta(a,b) and their covariance is p times the variance of a Beta(a,b) random variable. Adjust p so that this is the desired covariance rho, and you are done.

Comment: @Did wow!!! yeah, i thought about ur method just now and u are correct. Thank u very much and what a pity i didn't notice ur answer at that time. I used Gaussian copula to generate the random data. Thank you very much.